# Dart - Detect non-completing futures

Tags: dart, memory-leaks, future

I have a Dart console app that is calling into a third-party library.

When my console app calls the third-party library the call to the method returns however my CLI app then 'hangs' for 10 seconds or so before finally shutting down.

I suspect that the library has some type of resource that it has created but has not closed/completed.

My best guess is that it is a non-completed future.

So I'm looking for ways to detect resources that haven't been freed.

My first port of call would be looking for a technique to detect futures that haven't been completed but solutions for other resource types would be useful.

I'm currently using a runZoneGuarded, passing in a ZoneSpecification to hook calls.

Edit: with some experimentation, I've found I can detect timers and cancel them. In a simple experiment, I've found that a non-cancelled timer will cause the app to hang. If I cancel the timers (during my checkLeaks method) the app will shut down, however, this isn't enough in my real-world app so I'm still looking for ways to detect other resources.

Here is the experimental code I have:

```dart
#! /usr/bin/env dcli

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';
import 'package:onepub/src/pub/global_packages.dart';
import 'package:onepub/src/pub/system_cache.dart';
import 'package:onepub/src/version/version.g.dart';
import 'package:pub_semver/pub_semver.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  print(orange('OnePub version: $packageVersion '));

  print('');

  print(globals);

  // await globals.repairActivatedPackages();

  await runZonedGuarded(() async {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 20), () => print('timer done'));
    unawaited(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20)));
    var completer = Completer();
    unawaited(
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20), () => completer.complete()));

    //   await globals.activateHosted(
    //     'dcli_unit_tester',
    //     VersionConstraint.any,
    //     null, // all executables
    //     overwriteBinStubs: true,
    //     url: null, // hostedUrl,
    //   );
    print('end activate');
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    print('Uncaught error: $error');
  }, zoneSpecification: buildZoneSpec());

  print('end');

  checkLeaks();

  // await entrypoint(arguments, CommandSet.ONEPUB, 'onepub');
}

late final SystemCache cache = SystemCache(isOffline: false);
GlobalPackages? _globals;
GlobalPackages get globals => _globals ??= GlobalPackages(cache);

List<void Function()> actions = [];
List<Source<Timer>> timers = [];

int testCounter = 0;
int timerCount = 0;
int periodicCallbacksCount = 0;
int microtasksCount = 0;

ZoneSpecification buildZoneSpec() {
  return ZoneSpecification(
    createTimer: (source, parent, zone, duration, f) {
      timerCount += 1;
      final result = parent.createTimer(zone, duration, f);
      timers.add(Source(result));
      return result;
    },
    createPeriodicTimer: (source, parent, zone, period, f) {
      periodicCallbacksCount += 1;
      final result = parent.createPeriodicTimer(zone, period, f);
      timers.add(Source(result));
      return result;
    },
    scheduleMicrotask: (source, parent, zone, f) {
      microtasksCount += 1;
      actions.add(f);
      final result = parent.scheduleMicrotask(zone, f);
      return result;
    },
  );
}

void checkLeaks() {
  print(actions.length);
  print(timers.length);

  print('testCounter $testCounter');
  print('timerCount $timerCount');
  print('periodicCallbacksCount $periodicCallbacksCount');
  print('microtasksCount $microtasksCount');

  for (var timer in timers) {
    if (timer.source.isActive) {
      print('Active Timer: ${timer.st}');
      timer.source.cancel();
    }
  }
}

class Source<T> {
  Source(this.source) {
    st = StackTrace.current;
  }
  T source;
  late StackTrace st;
}
```

I'm my real-world testing I can see that I do have hanging timers caused by HTTP connections. As I originally guessed this does seem to point to some other problem with the HTTP connections not being closed down correctly.

```dart
Active Timer: #0      new Source (file:///home/bsutton/git/onepub/onepub/bin/onepub.dart:105:21)
#1      buildZoneSpec.<anonymous closure> (file:///home/bsutton/git/onepub/onepub/bin/onepub.dart:68:18)
#2      _CustomZone.createTimer (dart:async/zone.dart:1388:19)
#3      new Timer (dart:async/timer.dart:54:10)
#4      _HttpClientConnection.startTimer (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2320:18)
#5      _ConnectionTarget.returnConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2381:16)
#6      _HttpClient._returnConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2800:41)
#7      _HttpClientConnection.send.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2171:25)
#8      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
```

Comment: The third-party library should close HTTP connections when appropriate, or else provide a mechanism to manually do so. Are you able to open an issue ticket, or fork it?

Comment: An alternative way around this would be to fork the HTTP library that this library uses, globally keep track of client instantiations, and then expose their close functions.

Comment: The core point of this question is not to fix this specific issue but to have a generic tool for this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's impossible to find things that *doesn't* happen.

There is no way to find all futures in the program.

With a zone, you might be able to intercept all the callbacks being "registered" in the zone, but you can't know which of them must be called. A future can have both value handlers and an error handlers, and at most one of them will ever be called. So, just because a callback on a future isn't called, it doesn't mean the future didn't complete.

A future most likely won't keep the isolate alive, though.
An incompleted future will just be garbage collected if nothing important is hanging on to it.

The most likely culprits for keeping an isolate alive are timers and receive ports.
(The VM internal implementation of timers, and I/O, and sockets, all use receive ports, so it's really just the ports.)

Again, there is no way to *find* all open ports programmatically.
You need a debugger with memory inspection tools for that.

I'd recommend using the [developer tools](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/memory) to look for instances of `ReceivePort` or `RawReceivePort` that are not being garbage collected, and see whether they are still alive.

---

Also be careful with `runZonedGuarded`.

Since `runZonedGuarded` introduces a new error zone (because it introduces an uncaught error handler in the new zone), an error future created inside the zone will not be seen to complete outside the zone.

That means that the code:

```dart
await runZonedGuarded(() async {
```

will not work if the body throws. The error of the future is handled by the zone instead of the `await`, so the `await` just sees a future which never completes.

Comment: That isn't the problem. The zone was introduced in to find the source of the problem.

Comment: ACK. I've tried elaborating on the bigger issue too.

Comment: I found my problem, an unclosed http connection that held the app running due to an associated timer. However, I was hoping to build a package that could detect the source of these type of problems. I will look to ask a question that looks to answer that question.